# can't work with vscode python django html autocomplete features not working

Tags: html, django

first I created a project to work with django, but when I add index.html to it it doesn't autocomplete! When I type, nothing comes up, I also get an error like "This extension is deprecated because it is no longer maintained".

"!" in the html files of my codes.
When I put the tick I wanted autocomplete but it didn't happen and I searched a lot and couldn't find any result. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the following method for doing what you what to do.

1. open your vscode.
2. Go to setting and search emmet language in the search bar find it include the language and add a specific language.
3. After doing this save it and your vscode is ready to go.